# Switch between activities in Android and loop

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

As you can see in the following image, I have 2 activities.

"activity 1" starts "activity 2".

In step 3, when I press back button, "activity 2" appears! In fact an infinite loop happens when I press back button in activities(between step 2 and 3)!!!

I prefer not to override BACK BUTTON but as it seems I have to!!!

how can I fix it?

**# UPDATE** :

Step 1:

```
Intent Game_Activity = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Game_Activity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(Game_Activity);
```

Step 2:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
        //Return to Menu Activity
        Intent Sec_Activity = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
        startActivity(Sec_Activity);
}
```

Step 3:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    finish();
}
```

[image]

Comment: The question would really benefit from having some code. It's hard to debug without the real code and just a picture ;)

Comment: In step 2 are you finishing the second activity or calling startActivity(intent) ?

Comment: finish() activity 2 onbackpress ()

Comment: just call`finish();` after `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: As my answer says, the base mistake is using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT... The solution is not to use it.

Comment: Post your manifest. If you remove `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` as per @Raanan and remove all the overrides of `onBackPressed()`  this should work as desired. You must be doing something else strange.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the reorder to front flag, it's not necessary... when resuming if the app hasn't been destroyed the current activity is resumed.  This will restore normal back button behavior and activity order.

If you want to maintain the current state of the app even if it's removed from memory look into http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

This will be a good starting point.

Comment: I removed `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` but activity did not resume!

Comment: @Jessica I suggest you update the question with some more details on what you are doing... resuming the current activity is a basic feature of Android.  Could it be that you defined some flags regarding the 2nd Activity in the manifest? or are you calling finish somewhere?

Comment: You need to remove the FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flag and also remove the onBackPressed overrides they are both not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently came across to the same problem. Adding this to the Activity1 works for me.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
            Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startMain);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `Activity1` to `Activity2`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In `Activity2`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: She doesn't want to override the backbutton!!

Comment: actually you don't need to override the back button - the default behavior is finishing the current activity. this doesn't solve the question since she's using the reorder to front flag.

Answer (score 0):

In your first acticity step 1:

```
    Intent Game_Activity = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    Game_Activity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(Game_Activity);
   finish();
```

Add finish after intent.

Answer (score 0):

activity one

```
Intent Game_Activity = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Game_Activity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(Game_Activity);
```

activity two

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

}
```

**OR**

activity one

```
Intent Game_Activity = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Game_Activity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(Game_Activity);
finish();
```

activity two

```
public void onBackPressed() {
Intent i= new Intent(secondActivity.this, FirsActivity.class); 
    startActivity(i);
    finish()
}
```